# Best practise to export ADF pipelines, datasets, etc to another subsctiption

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

What's the best practise for exporting ADF pipelines, data sets, etc. to another subscription and ADF?
I know that you can choose the "ARM Template" drop down and select Export ARM template, then Import ARM template.
Or if you have source control set up, you could also clone the repo and connect that to a new ADF in a new subscription.
But what's the recommended/best practise way of doing this and how could it be automated?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how many times you are going to do this. If it is just once because you are moving to a different subscription, then just export ARM template and deploy it on the new subscription, thats just it.

If this will be a recurring thing, then the best practice is to automate this with Azure DevOps, as it is clearly explained here in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

I've found this pdf also to be really helpful when doing this for the first time: https://azure.microsoft.com/mediahandler/files/resourcefiles/whitepaper-adf-on-azuredevops/Azure%20data%20Factory-Whitepaper-DevOps.pdf

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The source control doesn't  really solve our issue.. We are a Microsoft partner and at times have to develop pipelines in our own Data Favtory and subscription. We then have to "move" those pipelines to a customer Data Factory and subscription, qhich will then be source controlled feom there in a different Devops Project and repo